# How to get one of the ImageFormat properties (like ImageFormat.Png or ImageFormat.Jpeg) dynamically?

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

Could you help me to solve some problem, please?

I want to get one of the ImageFormat properties (like ImageFormat.Png or ImageFormat.Jpeg, etc). And I need it dynamically. 
The method should look like (as I see it):

```
private List<ImageFormat> GetValidImageFormats()
    {
        List<ImageFormat> result = new List<ImageFormat>()
        foreach (string extension in ValidExtensions)
        {
            // do some expression magic
        }
    }
```

I have problem with with code in foreach. I dont even sure of using `Expression Trees`.

I need it for my custom validator for uploaded image files. Any help is just great. +1 for any relevant solution.

EDIT:
Possible values of `ValidExtensions` = `new[] {"jpg", "png", "jpeg", "bmp", "gif", "icon"}`

Comment: "jpg", "png", "jpeg", "bmp", "gif", "icon"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your list of extensions matches what's returned from the `ImageFormat` class, like this:

```
private List<string> ValidExtensions = new List<string> {"bmp", "jpeg", "png"};
```

You can convert each of those strings to their equivalent `ImageFormat` with reflection:

```
private List<ImageFormat> GetValidImageFormats()
{
    var t = typeof(ImageFormat);

    return ValidExtensions.Select(x =>
        (ImageFormat)t.GetProperty(x.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + x.Substring(1))
                      .GetValue(null)).ToList();

}
```

svick left an alternate solution in the comments, and it more clearly indicates your intention.

Instead of converting the string to title case to make it match the method call, you can use a different overload of `GetProperty()` to pass a bitmask telling it how to search... in this case, find a public static member and ignore the case altogether.

```
private List<ImageFormat> GetValidImageFormats()
{
    var t = typeof(ImageFormat);

    return ValidExtensions.Select(x =>
        (ImageFormat)t.GetProperty(x, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                      .GetValue(null)).ToList();

}
```

Comment: Actually it does not work. `ImageFormat` is not an enum, that is why ArgumentException is thrown.

Comment: It works! Some chages would be nice `x.Substring(1).ToLower()`. And I changed manually jpg to jpeg in `ValidExtensions` before returning.

Comment: Possibly clearer variant: `t.GetProperty(x, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)`.